# akka-http-testkit with akka-actor-testkit-typed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, akka-testkit, akka-typed

I am trying to test a TypedActor with akka-http and have issues while trying to create a Test case.
For testing a TypedActor, I would write the following Spec...

```
class MyServiceTestSpec extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit with FlatSpecLike with Matchers
```

But, when I would have to write a TypedActor used with HTTP /+ WS route, I am unable to write...

```
class MyHTTPServiceTestSpec extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit with FlatSpecLike with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest
```

This is because `system` member for `ScalaTestWithActorTestKit` is a typed.ActorSystem, while for ScalatestRouteTest is `ActorSystem` (untyped).

How would I be able to write a test that can use both?

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to do that out of the box, you will have to introduce some glue like the `ScalaTestWithActorTestKit` and `ActorTestKitBase` in your own test sources for now. There's an issue tracking improving on the situation here: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2036

Comment: I added `trait ScalatestTypedActorHttpRoute extends ScalatestRouteTest`. But, have to do some bad code of `var` for adapting the `ActorTestKit`'s system to untyped world of `ScalatestRouteTest.createActorSystem()`. Let me add my code snippet on the above issue.